# How to encode an array of elements to HTML

Tags: c#, html, arrays, razor

I have an array full of strings that have been taken from a form. I need to convert each element of the array to HTML before I post it to my database, in order to stop SQL errors occurring.

Here is a snippet of the array:

```
string[] device = {Request["image"] ,  Request["name"] , Request["nettech"] , Request["announced"] , Request["status"]};
```

I am using ASP, Razor and C# in addition to HTML and CSS to code the website. Is there an easy way to encode all the array elements, instead of doing them all individually (which works, just looking for a shorter, tidier way of doing things)?

This is how I am currently encoding them:

```
string image = Server.HtmlEncode(device[0]);
string name = Server.HtmlEncode(device[1]);
```

Comment: This sounds like you're constructing the query by hand without using named parameters, that's VERY dangerous as it will be really easy to hack with SQL injection, take a look at this if it's the case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx also using named parameters will scape all the data and there will be no need to encode your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wonder *why* inserting in the database goes wrong. Maybe you are concatenating strings. If so, you should worry about SQL injection attacks. I would advice to look into that.

If you want to call `Server.HtmlEncode` on every element in the array, you can simply do this:

```
device = device.Select(Server.HtmlEncode).ToArray();
```

Comment: That works perfectly! thank you :) I'll look into protecting from SQL injection, but I think my lecturer told us not to worry about it at this stage, thank you :)

Comment: Can you give his web server address? ;)